# Kivy on Raspberry Pi 4 terminates before showing window

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, raspberry-pi, kivy, sdl-2

When I run my Kivy application it terminates early. I followed the installation instructions on Kivy's website.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
import os
os.environ['KIVY_WINDOW'] = 'sdl2'
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'

Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass

class TheMonitorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheMonitorApp().run
```

main.kv

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Monitor"
            font_size: 32
```

Terminal

```
(kivy_venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/projects/HomeMonitor $ python main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-11-03_19.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/pi/projects/HomeMonitor/kivy_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/pi/projects/HomeMonitor/kivy_venv/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.2
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer 
(kivy_venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/projects/HomeMonitor $
```

Notice the terminal output stops at "[INFO   ] [Image       ]", why does it stop here? It still needs to reach "Window" and "GL".

Also if I delete these lines nothing changes:

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_WINDOW'] = 'sdl2'
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#installation-canonical

Install dependencies:
"For the Raspberry Pi, you must additionally install the dependencies listed in source dependencies before installing Kivy above."

Install kivy:
python -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples